# Altium Designer Keepout Region for Defined Polygon Nets

Tags: pcb, altium

I want to create a keepout zone for ethernet transformer sub in altium, but only the polygon pour of gnd will be blocked in this zone. I want to allow other polygon pours made in this other zone, how can I do that? i.e. how can I define a custom keepout for gnd?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use polygon pour cutout/keepout track functionality for this.
For your understanding see following image, in which I have made cutout of any shape using cutout functionality.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer ,i know this feature but i want this region to gnd polygon pour only to prevent this, other polgyouns remaining in this region will continue to be rendered.